# The menu-bar of any application should allways be displayed

Tags: menu-bar

How can I allways show the menu-bar (File, Edit...) of every application? not only when I move the pointer to the top, that is cumbersome.

edit: But now I (also) have to move the pointer to the top of the window to show the menu-bar. I want that the menu-bar is allways shown, not when I move the pointer.

Thanks.

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/682788

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer **CLI** method than run following command in terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity integrated-menus true
```

---

If you prefer **GUI** method than,

Goto **System-settings>Appearance** in **Behavior** and change settings for **Menu bar** as Following screen-shot:

[image: screen]

Now **Menu-bar** Separately available on each **window's Title bar**.

Comment: Okay, that's good. But now I (also) have to move the pointer to the top of the window to show the menu-bar. I want that the menu-bar is allways shown, not when I move the pointer.